# How to use WHERE in SQLite to display a particular date from an SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The query is:

```
 String query  = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE date = "+date;
```

Log is:

```
05-26 15:28:01.429 12647-12647/? D/TaskDB: querySELECT * FROM task WHERE date = 3-5-2017
```

For example, I want to access 3-5-2017 from this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi9bH.png).

Comment: **1** - Your dates are defined as strings, so treat them accordingly. **2** - Your date format is wrong. A valid timestring for a date has this format: `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: storing date as a string in your database make handling it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For String data types, always use quotes like this '" + date + "'". 
Since date is a String you get the error.
You should use + date only if date is not a String.
So your query should be:

```
String query  = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE date = '" + date + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get date form task table by  a simple query.

```
    private SQLiteDatabase database = null;

private String getDate()
{
 String query="select date from task where id='2'";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
               Log.d("Query Result ", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
        }
while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
retrun cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
}
```